# JQuery unable bind function after dynamic HTML element creation

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

i have simple html creation like this :

```
$('#date_'+user_id).append('<input  type="text" size="20" id="date_new_'+user_id+'" value="'+dateStr+'"/>');
```

as you can see the id is dynamic then i try to bind function into it like this :

```
$('#date_new_'+user_id+"'").bind({
    click: function() {
    alert("do something on click");
     },
    mouseenter: function() {
    alert("do something on mouseenter"); 
}
```

});

again as you can see im using dynamic id ( the one i created ) 
but it gives me error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #date_new_97' jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
bc.error jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
bh jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
bp jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
r.querySelectorAll.bp jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
bc jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.fn.extend.find jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.fn.p.init jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
(anonymous function)
p.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
g.handle.h
```

i do see the text element created via chrome developer tools and firebug

Comment: You are missing `)` for the bind function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#date_new_'+user_id+"'")` is your problem.

Given this case:

```
var user_id = 15;
var jquery_selector = '#date_new_'+user_id+"'";
```

`jquery_selector` is now `#date_new_15'` instead of `#date_new_15`. Notice the trailing single quotation mark.

Change it to `$('#date_new_'+user_id)` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#date_new_'+user_id).bind({
    click: function() {
    alert("do something on click");
     },
    mouseenter: function() {
    alert("do something on mouseenter"); 
});
```

but if you add dynamically the input I suggest you to use this code:

```
$(document).on('click','#date_new_'+user_id, function() {
    alert("do something on click");
     } 
});
$(document).on('mouseenter','#date_new_'+user_id, function() {
    alert("do something on mouseenter");
     } 
});
```